# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Flask' and 'Flask' - PyTest

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I'm trying to set up `PyTest` for flask and hit the error TypeError:

`unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Flask' and 'Flask'`

I have two fixtures in a `conftest.py` file:

```py
from application import init_app, db

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_app():
    """fixture for testing the application"""
    app - init_app()
    app.config.from_object("app.config.TestingConfig")
    with app.app_context():
        yield app


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_db():
    """fixture for cleaning and initializing the database"""
    db.create_all()
    yield db
    db.session.remove()
    db.drop_all()
```

And then I have a couple of tests just testing my config file:

```py
"""Tests the flask app configuration app.config.py"""


def test_config(test_app):
    test_app.config.from_object("app.config.Config")
    assert test_app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] == "Super_Secret"
    assert not test_app.config["TESTING"]
    assert test_app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] == "mysql+pymysql://root:"


def test_testing_config(test_app):
    test_app.config.from_object("app.config.TestingConfig")
    assert test_app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] == "mysql+pymysql://root:"
    assert test_app.config["TESTING"]
```

and for context, I import my init_app so here that is:

```py
def init_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    # Setup plugins
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    JWTManager.init_app(app)
    migration.init_app(app, db)
    mail.init_app(app)
    cors.init_app(app)

    from application.models import Answers

    with app.app_context():
        # Blueprints
        
        from application.answers import answers_blueprint

        app.register_blueprint(answers_blueprint)
       

        return app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo on `app - init_app()`:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def test_app():
    """fixture for testing the application"""
    # app - init_app() # Typo here, should be = instead of -
    app = init_app()
    app.config.from_object("app.config.TestingConfig")
    with app.app_context():
        yield app
```